# How to start a tween in FlowEnt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm using the FlowEnt library and I created a tween but it doesn't start
here's the code

```
transform.Tween(3f).MoveTo(destination);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animations in FlowEnt don't automatically start. The library has 2 options:
Auto-Start and True-Start. As per their website, the True-Start is faster, but Auto-Start was implemented in order to provide people with familiar access. True-Start also provides an Async option. More info [here](https://flowent.friedsynapse.com/tips#h.s5cucrg5qyjc).

In terms of how to fix the animation, you can use the following

**True-Start**

```
transform.Tween(3f).MoveTo(destination).Start();
```

**True-Start** but async

```
await transform.Tween(3f).MoveTo(destination).StartAsync();
```

**Auto-Start**

```
transform.Tween(3f, true).MoveTo(destination);
```